# How do I get all the post tags in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get all the post tags in my WordPress. Below is my code in the footer:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$tags = get_terms('post_tag');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

With the above code I am getting only the tags associated with a specific post, not the entire list of tags in WordPress.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can user get_tags()

Comment: check this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [get_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) to get all posts tags

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags(array(
  'hide_empty' => false
));
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try This

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I was looking for this one.

Answer (score 4):

If someone wants to display the most popular you can use this code

```
<?php 
        $tags = get_tags(array(
            'smallest'                  => 10, 
            'largest'                   => 22,
            'unit'                      => 'px', 
            'number'                    => 10,  
            'format'                    => 'flat',
            'separator'                 => " ",
            'orderby'                   => 'count', 
            'order'                     => 'DESC',
            'show_count'                => 1,
            'echo'                      => false
        ));
        echo '<ul class="AddYourClassUl">';
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo '<li class="AddYourClassLi">' . $tag->name . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Super late but if you just want to grab the tags you've selected this worked for me!

```
<?php if( has_tag() ) : ?>
    <?php echo get_the_tag_list(); // Display tags as links ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: He asked about all wordpress tags

Answer (score 0):

**This one works perfect**

`<?php if( has_tag() ) : ?>`
 `<?php echo get_the_tag_list(); // Display tags as links ?>`
`<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).